# How do email analytics work?

Tags: email, analytics, privacy

While I haven't actually used it, an email analytics web app called Litmus [claims to](http://litmusapp.com/email-analytics) be able to track:

1. How long someone takes to read an email.
2. Whether it is forwarded.
3. Whether it is deleted.
4. Whether it is printed.
5. What email client was used to read it.

I'm curious about where it gets this information from. Most email clients i've seen don't even load external images without explicitly loading them, let alone javascript.

Even if a lot just support images, that wouldn't give away items 1-3.

Comment: Image bugs, like any other email analytics tool. I personally think they are evil - I always set my clients NOT to load images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my best guess. As [this link](http://litmusapp.com/help/analytics/how-it-works) rockinthesixstring posted says, it relies on images but not javascript.

**How long someone takes to read an email.**

Place several images in the email that take a while to load, if the email is read for a long time, more are loaded.

**Whether it is forwarded.**

Is the image loaded from more than one IP/user agent?

**Whether it is deleted.**

The screenshots show this combined with glanced.

**Whether it is printed.**

Add a background image bug to a print stylesheet.

**What email client was used to read it.**

Check the user agent.

Answer (score 1):

Any email analytics application I've seen use an image tracker.  Basically if you attach a code generated 1x1 px image somewhere in the email, then during the loading of that image on the server side, you capture all of the `ServerVariables`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28VS.90%29.aspx

## EDIT:

I just read some of the information on the Litmus website an it looks as though it confirms what I wrote above regarding [image tracking](http://litmusapp.com/help/analytics/how-it-works)

Comment: That provides a good bit of data, particularly the client information and could even be used to track where a particular email goes (use a unique image file for each email, track filename/id). I'm not sure how you would use an image like that to track the times and whether or not it was deleted, though... do ServerVariables handle that?

Comment: @peachykeen please see my edit.  They DO in fact us an image... or more accurately IMAGES. It's actually not rocket science if you know what you're doing.